# Fancybox, using on() (live) to bind document by dynamic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

With fancybox you can usually use this function to bind document information:

```
$("#someID").on('click', function() {
```

Now I'm opening my fancybox content dynamically, here's an example:

```
function openFancyBox(id, type)
{
    if(type != 'default')
    {
        CurrentFeaturePositionID = id;

        $.fancybox({
            type: 'inline',
            'content' : $('#' + type + '_fb').html()
        });
    }
}
```

How do I bind the content using this method?

Comment: If you already have an element I would suggest using `$.fancybox($('#' + type + '_fb'))`

Comment: before fancybox you could do `var el = $('#' + type + '_fb')` then bind it as `el.on()` or `el.find(".someclass").on()`